# WSO2 IS: CVE-2017-12615 and CVE-2017-12616

Tags: tomcat, wso2

In the light of recently discovered Tomcat vulnerabilities which allow remote code execution in versions 7.0.0 through 7.0.79 (CVE-2017-12615 and CVE-2017-12616) what would be the recommendation to WSO2 IS users?
WSO2 IS uses customized versions of tomcat with latest being 7.0.70 which makes all WSO2 IS versions vulnerable.

Any idea when patch will be released and what actions users can undertake in the meantime ?

Thank you!

Comment: The correct channel to report security concerns of WSO2 products is security@wso2.com - not in public forums like SO. Therefore, could you please remove this post and report at security@wso2.com ASAP? Thanks!

Comment: This question and the comment of drox help to find the [rigth way](https://wso2.com/security) for reporting security issues. For me it is not to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 has already released patches for upgrading the underlying tomcat version up to 7.0.77. The patches are publicly released only for the latest versions of the products. The particular security advisory can be found in (1) which has patches for latest product versions.

For public/free users of WSO2, it is always recommended to use the latest versions.

(1) https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisory+WSO2-2017-0255

Comment: Hi Thank you for the prompt response! Using most recent version of WSO2 IS and applying all the patches regularly is surely the right way to go. The only concern here is that CVE-2017-12615 mentions that all Tomcat versions from 7.0.0 through 7.0.79 are vulnerable while security patch that was released by WSO2 upgrades Tomcat to only 7.0.77 ...which is still a vulnerable version. Could you comment on this pls?